# Immutable Objects and Initialization Safety with Thread Safety

Tags: java, multithreading

A note from the **The Java Concurrency In Practice**

> Immutable objects can be used safely by any thread without additional
>   synchronization, even when synchronization is not used to publish them

What I get is that they are **thread - safe**.

A snippet from Jeremy Manson blog-

```
class String {
  // Don't do this, either.
  static String lastConstructed;
  private final byte[] bytes;
  public String(byte[] value) {
    bytes = new byte[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, bytes, 0, value.length);
    lastConstructed = this;         
  }
}
```

Since the this reference is being stored in **lastConstructed**" hence **Escaping the constructor**

Ofcourse, it would work if you made lastConstructed volatile (postJDK5+ semantics)

One of the questions asked there is-

> If lastConstructed was volatile but then the reference was unsafely
>   published to another thread, then the String would not be immutable.
>   Right?

to which Jeremy's reply was-

It wouldn't be thread-safe because it was immutable, but it would be thread-safe because lastConstructed was volatile.

I perfectly understand that it would be thread-safe because lastConstructed was volatile, but I don't get **It wouldn't be thread-safe because it was immutable**.

Why? The note from Concurrency In Practice says Immutable objects can be used safely by any thread (i.e Thread Safety guarantee). If something is immutable, then it is thread safe.

Please suggest.

Comment: You can't publish a reference to an object and expect it to be used or have anything to do with a `static` field.

Comment: Maybe he means that only immutability itself doesn't guarantee thread-safety (so if you have static fields, that are common to all objects of the class, you need make them volatile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mis-understanding is that you have Object fields in Java. You only have references and primitives.  This means that

```
static String lastConstructed;
```

The field `lastConstructed` is a *mutable* reference.  It's visibility is not thread safe.  Having an immutable object doesn't confer any properties on a reference to that object.

Similarly if you have a `final` field, this doesn't make your Object immutable.

```
final Date today = new Date();
```

`today` is not immutable just because you made one reference to it `final`.

A more subtle on is in the use of `volatile`  You have to be careful as to whether you are reading or write the volatile value. Even if you do

```
volatile Date now = new Date();

now.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); // no thread safe.
```

There is two reasons this is not thread safe. 1) The access to `now` is a read not a write and secondly it occurs before the write in any case. What is required is a write barrier after. Something you see what appears to be nonsense.

```
now = now; // this adds a write barrier.
```

A related myth is that if you use a thread safe collection, any series of operations you perform is also thread safe.  It's a bit like fairy dust, you just sprinkle it around and many of your bugs disappear, but this doesn't mean you really are thread safe.

In short, thread safety is like a chain of dependencies, if any aspect of how data is accessed is not thread safe, none of it is.

Note: adding some thread safe constructs can hide thread safety issues, but it doesn't fix them, it just means that some change in JVM, or OS or hardware will break your code in the future.

Comment: Final fields can't be modified although the objects they refer to can be modified if they are mutable(today field is final hence immutable but new Date() is mutable.) Am I correct?

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari correct. The `Date` object can still be mutated.

Comment: If I declare the  lastConstructed as a final static field, in that case, it would be thread safe. Right.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari yes, provided the object is also thread safe or immutable.

Comment: When you said, 'today is not immutable just because you made one reference to it final.'. I think by today, you're referring to the object it is pointing to., i.e new Date(). I am little confused with today is not immutable. Final fields are always immutable, as they can't be modified.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari Yes, the Object is still mutable even if the reference is not.

Comment: `now = now; // this adds a write barrier.` Whenever one wish to do any operation on `now`, the first would be reading it. And then write would follow. Between them is the write barrier. Was this you meant?

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari yes, reading them is less tricky as you can do `now.getTime()` and you have a read barrier.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari, if you declared `lastConstructed` as a final static field, it wouldn't compile because you're reassigning it on every string creation which contradicts the `final` meaning.

Comment: @Andrew: My bad... Impressive.

Answer (score 2):

Though @Peter Lawrey has explained the details and problems of designing thread safe and immutable classes, and based on the further discussion, I think the question hasn't received the direct answer. So, I'd like to elaborate a bit:

The main problem in the understanding the phrase *"Immutable objects can be used safely by any thread"* is that it's not complete per se. It relies on the premise that any object must also be safely published to be thread-safe. Immutable objects is not an exception. So, the full phrase should be *"Immutable and safely published objects can be used safely by any thread."*

The problem in the `String` example is that it allows the reference to the object to escape from the constructor, thus presenting to other threads potentially invalid object state. For instance, if the compiler decides to optimize the constructor and rearrange operations for performance reasons this way:

```
public String(byte[] value) {
    bytes = new byte[value.length];
    lastConstructed = this;         
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, bytes, 0, value.length);
}
```

some other thread that reads `lastConstructed` will be able to see the string that is not fully constructed. So, the class is not thread safe, even though its instances are immutable.

Here we come to the meaning of the phrase *"It wouldn't be thread-safe because it was immutable"*. It means that immutability alone doesn't guarantee thread safety and the example proves it.

Making `lastConstructed` volatile would force the compiler to emit a memory barrier that would prevent the optimizer from rearranging operations in the way described above. It would guarantee that the array copying always happens before the assigning `lastConstructed = this`. As the result, another thread, that reads `lastConstructed`, would never see an underconstructed string. It would also guarantee that other threads would always read the actual value of `lastConstructed`. Thats why *"it would be thread-safe because lastConstructed was volatile"* in this particular case.

Comment: Suppose String.lastConstructed  was declared to be final. Now imagine, one thread is executing(reading) String.lastConstructed while in parallel, another thread was creating an object of the above String class. What would the value of the String.lastConstructed as seen by first thread.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari, `lastConstructed` cannot be final, it wouldn't compile because it's static and you're reassigning it in the instance constructor. `final` means that the value of the field cannot be changed after the first assigning.

Comment: Am I correct to say that static initialization happens before final initialization.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *final initialization*. Static initialization happens when a class is loaded into the memory. It only happens once per class, in contrast to the instance initialization provided by the instance constructor once per every object of the class.